# golang set value on time.Time

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    type t struct {
        N int
    }
    var n = t{42}
    fmt.Println(n.N)
    reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().FieldByName("N").SetInt(7)
    fmt.Println(n.N)
}
```

The prog below works the question is how do I do this with time.Time type like

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    type t struct {
        N time.Time
    }
    var n = t{ time.Now() }
    fmt.Println(n.N)
    reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().FieldByName("N"). (what func)   (SetInt(7) is only for int)         // there is not SetTime
    fmt.Println(n.N)
}
```

This is important because I plan to use it on generic struct

I really appreciate your help on this

Comment: The answers above are correct. I just want to remind that `time.Now()` is the function with brackets rather than `time.Now`. That's the mistake I have made.

Answer (score 15):

Simply call `Set()` with a `reflect.Value` of the time you want to set:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

func main() {
        type t struct {
                N time.Time
        }
        var n = t{time.Now()}
        fmt.Println(n.N)

        //create a timestamp in the future
        ft := time.Now().Add(time.Second*3600)

        //set with reflection
        reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().FieldByName("N").Set(reflect.ValueOf(ft))

        fmt.Println(n.N)
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer!!! I did not find any example of the Set function before. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3715287 thanks. Note that you should check with `CanSet` if this is doable, or your code will panic.